# What is the sense of naming invokables like classes?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm going trough [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) to learn more about modules in Zend Framework 2. In the [Module.php](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/Module.php) you can see

```
'invokables' => array(
  'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db' => 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Adapter\Db',
  'ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db' => 'ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db',
  'ZfcUser\Form\Login'                => 'ZfcUser\Form\Login',
  'zfcuser_user_service'              => 'ZfcUser\Service\User',
  'zfcuser_register_form_hydrator'    => 'Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods',
),
```

Now, what is the difference between giving classes a *real* abbr like "zfcuser_user_service" vs their fully qualified name? I assume, there is no technical difference, but maybe there is a convention how to name invokables, as ZF relies on them, how to name them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In contrary of the other answers, I can state that there *IS* a convention, which is to use fully [qualified class names](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) for service names wherever possible (and fake class names where the service is virtual and instance of another class).

If the problem is just about how [`ZfcUser`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/tree/0.1.0/) does it, I can tell you that `ZfcUser` is not state of the art (currently `0.1.*`) and needs a rewrite. You could look at [`BjyAuthorize`](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize/blob/1.1.1/config/services.config.php) for a better example.

I use either the *FQCN* (Fully Qualified Class Name) of the class that is defined as a service, or the *FQCN* of the interface it implements, which helps avoiding that the user consuming the service uses API not specified in the interface, and just in the implementing class.

Also, consider that it makes no real difference if you use `\` or `_` or lowercase or uppercase service names, since everything is [normalized in the service manager](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L698-L712).
That basically means that `zfcuser_service_user` or `ZfcUser\Service\User` are the same.

To recap, here's a good practice you could follow:

```php
'invokables' => array(
    // interface FQCN
    'Namespace\MyInterface' => 'Namespace\MyImplementation',

    // no interface available
    'Namespace\ClassName'   => 'Namespace\ClassName',

    // no interface nor own implementation available (similar to an alias)
    'Namespace\MyStuff'     => 'OtherNamespace\Stuff',
),
```

This is both easy to remember and allows end-users of your service to look for `Namespace\MyInterface` and find what they were looking for.

Use it also for factories and for services spawned from abstract classes if possible, since it makes things easier to remember for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Could you point me to the reference stating the convention? I've searched when I started using ZF2 a few months ago but couldn't find anything about naming conventions back than.

Comment: Me? :) The docs lack a lot of conventions anywhere, so I'm basically lordly stating it. You can eventually ask other contributors on the irc channels. The fact is that ZF2 is configuration over convention all over the place, so it is still up to the end user to decide what to do and where to do it. If you find a section where this could fit, I'll gladly PR zf2 docs to add it.

Comment: I'm with you with your convention ;). I think the **service aliases** part on the [serviceManager page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.service-manager.intro.html) would be a good place to place some guidance for alias naming. Or even create a seperate page for it. I'm on IRC from time to time (with nick `bramstroker`).

Comment: I opened a PR based on this answer.

Comment: Just an additional note: since PHP 5.5, we have a `::class` meta-constant that can be used to make static analysis stronger, allowing things such as `Namespace\MyInterface::class => Namespace\ClassName::class`. That Allows for easier refactoring and reduces the chances of introducing typos in service definitions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no convention about how aliases are named. You should only give your aliases a unique name so you don't get naming conflicts with other modules providing the same service.
I use the FQCN in my project as well, because it avoids any conflicts 100% and it is very clear which class you are requesting from the service manager.

In the end it all comes down to personal taste, but I'd try to confirm yourself mostly to a single naming strategy and not mix up several tastes.

Comment: I really think there must be a better reason why contributors of zf2 who have built the ZfcUser module mixed up the invokables.

Comment: I think the reason for this is that `zfcuser_user_service` and `zfcuser_register_form_hydrator` are both services which can be overwritten by the user. A FQCN as alias would confuse the user in that case.

Comment: The reason is that `ZfcUser` needs a rewrite/cleanup. That's all of it, so be patient or help with it :) No strange magic or fancy voodoo: ZfcUser is just no good at conventions right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention but I do think you should consider how the invokables will be used.

For example the first three rely on an interface called `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` therefore these instances need to come out of the `ServiceLocator` to function as intended. Given that they are fully qualified class names, I would assume that the ZfcUser developers do not envisage people overriding these.

And the latter two are aliased, so if a developer wanted to override these invokables it would be a straightforward task. An example of this is the developer chooses to extend `ZfcUser\Service\User` to add/modify functionality, then creates line in his module's invokables:

```
'invokables' => array(
  'zfcuser_user_service' => 'MyModule\Service\ZfcUser',
),
```

Then any code using `zfcuser_user_service` would receive an instance of `MyModule\Service\ZfcUser` rather than `ZfcUser\Service\User`.