# Zend Framework 2. Invokables

Tags: controller, zend-framework2

```
                return array(
                'router' => array(
                    'routes' => array(
                        'wall' => array(
                            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/api/wall[/:id]',
                                'constraints' => array(
                                    'id' => '\w+'
                                ),
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Wall\Controller\Index'
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'controllers' => array(
                    'invokables' => array(
                        'Wall\Controller\Index' => 'Wall\Controller\IndexController',
                    ),
                ),
            );
```

I am looking at the configuration for a module Wall which is part of a JSON restfull API program with Zend Framework 2. In /myprogram/Wall/src/Controller directory there is a file IndexController.php and inside it the namespace is declared 'namespace Wall\Controller'. My question is about 'invokables'. The right hand side of '=>' makes sense to me it is referencing the controllers class name and namespace if I understand correctly. What is on the left hand side of '=>' I am still looking for an explanation of what is 'Wall\Controller\Index'.

Thank you for posting...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15039144/what-is-the-sense-of-naming-invokables-like-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really just a `key`. Arrays within the configuration are stored with the schema `key => value`. And the string `Module\Controller\Foo` is just it's name. You could write `module-controller-foo`, too, and use it like this within your route configuration.

Comment: In case there'll be more downvoters, please care to explain why you'd downvote this answer. Content wise there's nothing wrong so please explain your reasoning so I can improve upon them.

Answer (score 5):

`invokables` defines classes you can call. You would usually define classes that can be invoked like this:

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Some\Namespace\Class',
    'Some\Namespace\OtherClass',
),
```

You can also define aliases, by passing an array, like in the example you gave:

```
'invokables' => array(
    'Wall\Controller\Index' => 'Wall\Controller\IndexController',
),
```

It defines `Wall\Controller\Index` invokable as an alias for `Wall\Controller\IndexController`.